# Python 3 bytes formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

In Python 3, one can format a string like:

```
"{0}, {1}, {2}".format(1, 2, 3)
```

But how to format bytes?

```
b"{0}, {1}, {2}".format(1, 2, 3)
```

raises `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'format'`.

If there is no `format` method for bytes, how to do the formatting or "rewriting" of bytes?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As of Python 3.5, `%` formatting will work for `bytes`, too!

This was part of [PEP 461](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2014-March/133620.html), authored by Ethan Furman:

```
PEP: 461
Title: Adding % formatting to bytes and bytearray
Version: $Revision$
Last-Modified: $Date$
Author: Ethan Furman <ethan at stoneleaf.us>
Status: Draft
Type: Standards Track
Content-Type: text/x-rst
Created: 2014-01-13
Python-Version: 3.5
Post-History: 2014-01-14, 2014-01-15, 2014-01-17, 2014-02-22, 2014-03-25,
               2014-03-27
Resolution:


Abstract
========

This PEP proposes adding % formatting operations similar to Python 2's ``str``
type to ``bytes`` and ``bytearray`` [1]_ [2]_.


Rationale
=========

While interpolation is usually thought of as a string operation, there are
cases where interpolation on ``bytes`` or ``bytearrays`` make sense, and the
work needed to make up for this missing functionality detracts from the overall
readability of the code.


Motivation
==========

With Python 3 and the split between ``str`` and ``bytes``, one small but
important area of programming became slightly more difficult, and much more
painful -- wire format protocols [3]_.

This area of programming is characterized by a mixture of binary data and
ASCII compatible segments of text (aka ASCII-encoded text).  Bringing back a
restricted %-interpolation for ``bytes`` and ``bytearray`` will aid both in
writing new wire format code, and in porting Python 2 wire format code.

Common use-cases include ``dbf`` and ``pdf`` file formats, ``email``
formats, and ``FTP`` and ``HTTP`` communications, among many others.
```

PEP 461 was [accepted by Guido van Rossum on March 27, 2014](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2014-March/133621.html):

> Accepted. Congrats with marshalling yet another quite contentious
> discussion, and putting up with my last-minute block-headedness!

From this, we can obviously conclude that `%` is no longer scheduled for deprecation (as was announced with Python 3.1).

Answer (score 31):

Another way would be:

```
"{0}, {1}, {2}".format(1, 2, 3).encode()
```

Tested on IPython 1.1.0 & Python 3.2.3

Comment: This doesn't work if your format arguments are bytes.

Comment: This does not work when you need to insert hard byte codes in the stream that are not supported by Unicode.

Answer (score 18):

Interestingly `.format()` doesn't appear to be supported for byte-sequences; as you have demonstrated.

You could use `.join()` as suggested here: http://bugs.python.org/issue3982

```
b", ".join([b'1', b'2', b'3'])
```

There is a speed advantage associated with `.join()` over using `.format()` shown by the BDFL himself: http://bugs.python.org/msg180449

Comment: Thanks! The message by BDFL is great find, too. However, this does not solve formatting of, say, floats. It would be interesting to know if there is any other way besides `str(some_bytes).encode()`

Comment: Understood. A `.format()` method for bytes does appear to be on track for inclusion in 3.4+

Comment: @bernie: But the `__format__` method of an object and built-in `format` return `str`. How will that work with `bytes` and encodings?

Comment: @bernie: [`bytes.format()` pep is withdrawn](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0460/). [printf-style formatting (%-interpolation) is introduced in Python 3.5 instead](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0461/)

Answer (score 18):

I found the `%b` working best in Python 3.6.2, it should work both for b"" and "":

```
print(b"Some stuff %b. Some other stuff" % my_byte_or_unicode_string)
```

Comment: it should be `%b` not `%a` for byte string, otherwise 'b' prefix is included

Comment: It doesn't work in Python 2.7.16 though, so it's not backward-compatible.

Comment: It doesn't work with unicode string. Only b'' is supported.

Answer (score 13):

For Python 3.6+ you can use this nice and clean syntax:

```
f'foo {bar}'.encode() # a byte string
```

Comment: This does formatting on `str`, not `bytes`. For example, it won't give the intended result if `bar` is a `bytes` object. Or if you want to put non-ASCII byte values in the format string.

Comment: @interjay of course there are all sorts of cases, where my solution wouldn't be helpful, including the one you mentioned. But this doesn't negate the fact there are remaining cases, including the one I had, when the solution works.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because describes the simplest and best solution.

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of [Schcriher's answer](/a/21021433/4518341) and has the exact same problems.

Answer (score -4):

I've found this to work.

```
a = "{0}, {1}, {2}".format(1, 2, 3)

b = bytes(a, encoding="ascii")

>>> b
b'1, 2, 3'
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Schcriher's answer](/a/21021433/4518341), just using a different encoding process