# Why does "bytes(n)" create a length n byte string instead of converting n to a binary representation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to build this bytes object in Python 3:

`b'3\r\n'`

so I tried the obvious (for me), and found a weird behaviour:

```
>>> bytes(3) + b'\r\n'
b'\x00\x00\x00\r\n'
```

Apparently:

```
>>> bytes(10)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I've been unable to see any pointers on why the bytes conversion works this way reading the documentation. However, I did find some surprise messages in this Python issue about adding `format` to bytes (see also [Python 3 bytes formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15710515/554319)):

http://bugs.python.org/issue3982

> This interacts even more poorly with oddities like bytes(int) returning zeroes now

and:

> It would be much more convenient for me if bytes(int) returned the ASCIIfication of that int; but honestly, even an error would be better than this behavior.  (If I wanted this behavior - which I never have - I'd rather it be a classmethod, invoked like "bytes.zeroes(n)".)

Can someone explain me where this behaviour comes from?

Comment: It is unclear from your question if you want the integer value 3, or the value of the ASCII character representing number three (integer value 51).  The first is bytes([3]) == b'\x03'.  The latter is bytes([ord('3')]) == b'3'.

Comment: What's wrong with: `("3" + "\r\n").encode()`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Python 3.5+ introduces %-interpolation (`printf`-style formatting) for bytes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-bytes-formatting):

```
>>> b'%d\r\n' % 3
b'3\r\n'
```

See [PEP 0461 -- Adding % formatting to bytes and bytearray](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0461/).

On earlier versions, you could use `str` and `.encode('ascii')` the result:

```
>>> s = '%d\r\n' % 3
>>> s.encode('ascii')
b'3\r\n'
```

Note: It is different from [what `int.to_bytes` produces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/846038/4279):

```
>>> n = 3
>>> n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big') or b'\0'
b'\x03'
>>> b'3' == b'\x33' != b'\x03'
True
```

Answer (score 349):

From python 3.2 you can use [`to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes):

```py
>>> (1024).to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')
b'\x04\x00'
```

```py
def int_to_bytes(x: int) -> bytes:
    return x.to_bytes((x.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big')
    
def int_from_bytes(xbytes: bytes) -> int:
    return int.from_bytes(xbytes, 'big')
```

Accordingly, `x == int_from_bytes(int_to_bytes(x))`.
Note that the above encoding works only for unsigned (non-negative) integers.

For signed integers, the bit length is a bit more tricky to calculate:

```py
def int_to_bytes(number: int) -> bytes:
    return number.to_bytes(length=(8 + (number + (number < 0)).bit_length()) // 8, byteorder='big', signed=True)

def int_from_bytes(binary_data: bytes) -> Optional[int]:
    return int.from_bytes(binary_data, byteorder='big', signed=True)
```

Comment: While this answer is good, it works only for unsigned (non-negative) integers. I have adapted it write an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54141411/832230) which also works for signed integers.

Comment: That doesn't help with getting `b"3"` from `3`, as the question asks. (It'll give `b"\x03"`.)

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that both ``to_bytes`` and ``from_bytes`` support a ``signed`` argument. This allows storing both positive and negative numbers, at the cost of an additional bit.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64502258/5267751 explains what the `+7` is for.)

Comment: Why are the parenthesis needed and where can I find documentation on them?

Comment: Didn't know there was a  X.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big'). And you can set the byte order! HUGE thank you!

Answer (score 257):

That's the way it was designed - and it makes sense because usually, you would call `bytes` on an iterable instead of a single integer:

```
>>> bytes([3])
b'\x03'
```

The [docs state this](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#binaryseq), as well as the docstring for `bytes`:

```
>>> help(bytes)
...
bytes(int) -> bytes object of size given by the parameter initialized with null bytes
```

Comment: Beware that the above works only with python 3. In python 2 `bytes` is just an alias for `str`, which means `bytes([3])` gives you `'[3]'`.

Comment: Creating a sequence first is incredibly slow for a single integer. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: In Python 3, note that `bytes([n])` only works for int n from 0 to 255. For anything else it raises `ValueError`.

Comment: @A-B-B: Not really surprising since a byte can only store values between 0 and 255.

Comment: It should also be noted that `bytes([3])` is still different from what the OP wanted – namely the byte value used to encode the digit "3" in ASCII, ie. `bytes([51])`, which is `b'3'`, not `b'\x03'`.

Comment: This is the wrong answer; it only works for integers 0 <= x < 256.

Comment: @weberc2: What do you mean? `bytes(500)` works perfectly well, and `bytes([500])` can't work since a byte can only have values between 0 and 255 (see comments above).

Comment: `bytes(500)` creates a bytestring w/ len == 500. It does not create a bytestring that encodes the integer 500. And I agree that `bytes([500])` can't work, which is why that's the wrong answer too. Probably the right answer is `int.to_bytes()` for versions >= 3.1.

Comment: For ASCII just do `bytes[n + 48]` for numbers between 0 and 9, or in the example with the number 3, `bytes[3 + 48]`, since the ASCII representation for 0 is `48`.

Answer (score 52):

You can use the [struct's pack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack):

```
In [11]: struct.pack(">I", 1)
Out[11]: '\x00\x00\x00\x01'
```

The ">" is the [byte-order (big-endian)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) and the "I" is the [format character](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters). So you can be specific if you want to do something else:

```
In [12]: struct.pack("<H", 1)
Out[12]: '\x01\x00'

In [13]: struct.pack("B", 1)
Out[13]: '\x01'
```

*This works the same on both python 2 and [python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).*

Note: the inverse operation (bytes to int) can be done with [unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack).

Comment: @AndyHayden To clarify, since a struct has a standard size irrespective of the input, `I`, `H`, and `B` work till `2**k - 1` where k is 32, 16, and 8 respectively. For larger inputs they raise `struct.error`.

Comment: Presumably down-voted as it doesn't answer the question: the OP wants to know how to generate `b'3\r\n'`, i.e. a byte-string containing the ASCII character "3" not the ASCII character "\x03"

Comment: @DaveJones What makes you think that is what the OP wants? The **accepted answer** returns `\x03`, and the solution if you just want `b'3'` is trivial. The reason cited by A-B-B is much more plausible... or at least understandable.

Comment: @DaveJones Also, the reason I added this answer was because Google takes you here when searching to do precisely this. So that's why it's here.

Comment: Not only does this work the same in 2 and 3, but it's faster than both the `bytes([x])` and `(x).to_bytes()` methods in Python 3.5. That was unexpected.

Answer (score 13):

The documentation says:

```
bytes(int) -> bytes object of size given by the parameter
              initialized with null bytes
```

The sequence:

```
b'3\r\n'
```

It is the character '3' (decimal 51) the character '\r' (13) and '\n' (10).

Therefore, the way would treat it as such, for example:

```
>>> bytes([51, 13, 10])
b'3\r\n'

>>> bytes('3', 'utf8') + b'\r\n'
b'3\r\n'

>>> n = 3
>>> bytes(str(n), 'ascii') + b'\r\n'
b'3\r\n'
```

Tested on IPython 1.1.0 & Python 3.2.3

Comment: I ended up doing `bytes(str(n), 'ascii') + b'\r\n'` or `str(n).encode('ascii') + b'\r\n'`. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Juanlu001, also `"{}\r\n".format(n).encode()` I don't think there is any harm done by using the default utf8 encoding

Answer (score 8):

The ASCIIfication of 3 is `"\x33"` not `"\x03"`!

That is what python does for `str(3)` but it would be totally wrong for bytes, as they should be considered arrays of binary data and not be abused as strings.

The most easy way to achieve what you want is `bytes((3,))`, which is better than `bytes([3])` because initializing a list is much more expensive, so never use lists when you can use tuples. You can convert bigger integers by using `int.to_bytes(3, "little")`.

Initializing bytes with a given length makes sense and is the most useful, as they are often used to create some type of buffer for which you need some memory of given size allocated. I often use this when initializing arrays or expanding some file by writing zeros to it.

Comment: There are several problems with this answer: (a) The escape notation of `b'3'`is `b'\x33'`, not `b'\x32'`. (b) `(3)` is not a tuple – you have to add a comma. (c) The scenario of initialising a sequence with zeroes does not apply to `bytes` objects, as they are immutable (it makes sense for `bytearray`s, though).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I fixed those two obvious mistakes. In case of `bytes` and `bytearray`, I think it's mostly a matter of consistency. But it is also useful if you want to push some zeros into a buffer or file, in which case it is only used as a data source.

Answer (score 6):

Although the prior [answer by brunsgaard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30375198/) is an efficient encoding, it works only for unsigned integers. This one builds upon it to work for both signed and unsigned integers.

```
def int_to_bytes(i: int, *, signed: bool = False) -> bytes:
    length = ((i + ((i * signed) < 0)).bit_length() + 7 + signed) // 8
    return i.to_bytes(length, byteorder='big', signed=signed)

def bytes_to_int(b: bytes, *, signed: bool = False) -> int:
    return int.from_bytes(b, byteorder='big', signed=signed)

# Test unsigned:
for i in range(1025):
    assert i == bytes_to_int(int_to_bytes(i))

# Test signed:
for i in range(-1024, 1025):
    assert i == bytes_to_int(int_to_bytes(i, signed=True), signed=True)
```

For the encoder, `(i + ((i * signed) < 0)).bit_length()` is used instead of  just `i.bit_length()` because the latter leads to an inefficient encoding of -128, -32768, etc.

---

Credit: CervEd for fixing a minor inefficiency.

Comment: `int_to_bytes(-128, signed=True) == (-128).to_bytes(1, byteorder="big", signed=True)` is `False`

Comment: You're not using length 2, you're calculating the bit length of the signed integer, adding 7, and then 1, if it's a signed integer. Finally you convert that into the length in bytes. This yields unexpected results for `-128`, `-32768` etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194383/discussion-between-cerved-and-a-b-b).

Comment: This is how you fix it `(i+(signed*i<0)).bit_length()`

Answer (score 5):

I was curious about performance of various methods for a single int in the range `[0, 255]`, so I decided to do some timing tests.

Based on the timings below, and from the general trend I observed from trying many different values and configurations, `struct.pack` seems to be the fastest, followed by `int.to_bytes`, `bytes`, and with `str.encode` (unsurprisingly) being the slowest. Note that the results show some more variation than is represented, and `int.to_bytes` and `bytes` sometimes switched speed ranking during testing, but `struct.pack` is clearly the fastest.

Results in CPython 3.7 on Windows:

```
Testing with 63:
bytes_: 100000 loops, best of 5: 3.3 usec per loop
to_bytes: 100000 loops, best of 5: 2.72 usec per loop
struct_pack: 100000 loops, best of 5: 2.32 usec per loop
chr_encode: 50000 loops, best of 5: 3.66 usec per loop
```

Test module (named `int_to_byte.py`):

```
"""Functions for converting a single int to a bytes object with that int's value."""

import random
import shlex
import struct
import timeit

def bytes_(i):
    """From Tim Pietzcker's answer:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/21017834/8117067
    """
    return bytes([i])

def to_bytes(i):
    """From brunsgaard's answer:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/30375198/8117067
    """
    return i.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')

def struct_pack(i):
    """From Andy Hayden's answer:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/26920966/8117067
    """
    return struct.pack('B', i)

# Originally, jfs's answer was considered for testing,
# but the result is not identical to the other methods
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/31761722/8117067

def chr_encode(i):
    """Another method, from Quuxplusone's answer here:
    https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/210789/140921
    
    Similar to g10guang's answer:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/51558790/8117067
    """
    return chr(i).encode('latin1')

converters = [bytes_, to_bytes, struct_pack, chr_encode]

def one_byte_equality_test():
    """Test that results are identical for ints in the range [0, 255]."""
    for i in range(256):
        results = [c(i) for c in converters]
        # Test that all results are equal
        start = results[0]
        if any(start != b for b in results):
            raise ValueError(results)

def timing_tests(value=None):
    """Test each of the functions with a random int."""
    if value is None:
        # random.randint takes more time than int to byte conversion
        # so it can't be a part of the timeit call
        value = random.randint(0, 255)
    print(f'Testing with {value}:')
    for c in converters:
        print(f'{c.__name__}: ', end='')
        # Uses technique borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/q/19062202/8117067
        timeit.main(args=shlex.split(
            f"-s 'from int_to_byte import {c.__name__}; value = {value}' " +
            f"'{c.__name__}(value)'"
        ))
```

Comment: @A-B-B As mentioned in my first sentence, I'm only measuring this for a single int in the range `[0, 255]`. I assume by "wrong indicator" you mean my measurements weren't general enough to fit most situations? Or was my measuring methodology poor? If the latter, I would be interested to hear what you have to say, but if the former, I never claimed my measurements were generic to all use-cases. For my (perhaps niche) situation, I am only dealing with ints in the range `[0, 255]`, and that is the audience I intended to address with this answer. Was my answer unclear? I can edit it for clarity...

Comment: What about the technique of just indexing a precomputed encoding for the range? The precomputation wouldn't be subject to timing, only the indexing would be.

Comment: @A-B-B That's a good idea. That sounds like it will be faster than anything else. I'll do some timing and add it to this answer when I have some time.

Comment: If you really want to time the bytes-from-iterable thing, you should use `bytes((i,))` instead of `bytes([i])` because list are more complex, use more memory and take long to initialize. In this case, for nothing.

Answer (score 4):

From [bytes docs](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes):

> Accordingly, constructor arguments are interpreted as for bytearray().

Then, from [bytearray docs](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray):

> The optional source parameter can be used to initialize the array in a few different ways:
>
> - If it is an integer, the array will have that size and will be initialized with null bytes.

Note, that differs from 2.x (where x >= 6) behavior, where `bytes` is simply `str`:

```
>>> bytes is str
True
```

[PEP 3112](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3112-byte-literals):

> The 2.6 str differs from 3.0’s bytes type in various ways; most notably, the constructor is completely different.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour comes from the fact that in Python prior to version 3 `bytes` was just an alias for `str`. In Python3.x `bytes` is an immutable version of `bytearray` - completely new type, not backwards compatible.

Answer (score 4):

`int` (including Python2's `long`) can be converted to `bytes` using following function:

```
import codecs

def int2bytes(i):
    hex_value = '{0:x}'.format(i)
    # make length of hex_value a multiple of two
    hex_value = '0' * (len(hex_value) % 2) + hex_value
    return codecs.decode(hex_value, 'hex_codec')
```

The reverse conversion can be done by another one:

```
import codecs
import six  # should be installed via 'pip install six'

long = six.integer_types[-1]

def bytes2int(b):
    return long(codecs.encode(b, 'hex_codec'), 16)
```

Both functions work on both Python2 and Python3.

Comment: 'hex_value = '%x' % i' will not work under Python 3.4. You get a TypeError, so you'd have to use hex() instead.

Comment: @bjmc replaced with str.format. This should work on Python 2.6+.

Comment: Thanks, @renskiy. You might want to use 'hex_codec' instead of 'hex' because it seems like 'hex' alias is not available on all Python 3 releases see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12917604/845210

Comment: @bjmc fixed. Thanks

Comment: This fails on negative integers on python 3.6

Answer (score 3):

As you want to deal with binary representation, the best is to use `ctypes`.

```
import ctypes
x = ctypes.c_int(1234)
bytes(x)
```

You must use the specific integer representation (signed/unsigned and the number of bits: `c_uint8`, `c_int8`, `c_unit16`,...).

Answer (score 0):

Some answers don't work with large numbers.

Convert integer to the hex representation, then convert it to bytes:

```
def int_to_bytes(number):
    hrepr = hex(number).replace('0x', '')
    if len(hrepr) % 2 == 1:
        hrepr = '0' + hrepr
    return bytes.fromhex(hrepr)
```

Result:

```
>>> int_to_bytes(2**256 - 1)
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can convert the int to str first, before you convert to byte.
That should produce the format you want.

```
bytes(str(your_number),'UTF-8') + b'\r\n'
```

It works for me in py3.8.

Answer (score -3):

```
>>> chr(116).encode()
b't'
```