# Hashing message gives the same hash for different values

Tags: python-3.x, hash, cryptography

I'm trying to write a code that will calculate 1000 SHA256 hashes from 3 randomly generated numbers( x1,x2,x3)
Ideally it should be in the loop from 1 to 1000 and all i need is to store the values somewhere in a list or array and analyze them later. 
When i'm running the code below, even though the random numbers are changing evry time, print(digest.finalize()) always returns the same hash

```
import random
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
while i<1000:
        digest = hashes.Hash(hashes.SHA256(), backend=default_backend())
        x1=random.randrange(2,256)
        x2=random.randrange(2,256)
        x3=random.randrange(2,256)
        print("x1,x2,x3 are ",x1,x2,x3)
        digest.update(b'x1')
        digest.update(b'x2')
        digest.update(b'x3')
        print(digest.finalize())
        del digest
        #print(digest.finalize())

        i=i+1
```

Comment: You are hashing the values of x1, x2, and x3, instead you are hashing the bytes object `b'x1x2x3'`.

Comment: not sure i understand. What do i have to change to make it work? Thanks

Comment: By learning the basics of python. In what programming language, a variable ```x``` is accessed by a string ```"x"```? :-)

Comment: By learning the basics of python??? Please @sascha leave the condescending tone  for other places. If you want to educate someone start with yourself. you might find this link useful https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/cryptographic-hashes/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting int to bytes in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Comment: @GeMi You understand, that **your link presents an example** and most crypto-based examples are working with some human-readable string. A String is not a variable! Even your code shows the difference somehow: **Hint:** the print-line.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. My comment should have started out "you are *not* hashing the values of x1, x2, and x3".

Answer (score 1):

Consider the difference between `digest.update(x1)` and `digest.update(b'x1')`. The latter simply supplies the characters b'x' and b'1' to the update method and has nothing at all to do with the variable `x1`.

To hash the value of the variable `x1` in

```
import random
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
digest = hashes.Hash(hashes.SHA256(), backend=default_backend())
x1=random.randrange(2,256)
```

you would need something like

```
digest.update(x1)
```

however, that is still incorrect because `update()` requires a bytes object for its argument, not an integer. Therefore the correct call is something like

```
digest.update(x1.to_bytes(1, 'big'))
```

Please read carefully the document for the `to_bytes` method of `int`.