# Python: Convert number in a list of bytes

Tags: python, list

I have to convert a number to a list depending on its decimal value. For example, the number `300`(`0x012C`) would be `[1, 44]` because `1` and `44` are `0x01` and `0x2c` respectively.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hu? `l` is not a syntactically valid list literal, and anyways, it contains `int`s not `bytes`

Comment: `l[0]*256+l[1]`?

Comment: I need decimal rapresentation of each byte of a number

Comment: Do you want to input 300 and get l = [1,44] or do you want to input l = [1,44] and get 300?

Comment: '300' -> [1, 44]

Comment: @itsp how did you get `0x2C` from `0x012C`? I don't really seem to understand how you are converting 300 to 1 and 44.

Comment: @StamKaly in the same way that `3254` -> `[32, 54]` I *believe*, but not sure...

Comment: I do another example. The number '9635' is in hex form 0x25A3. So in each field of the list I want the decimal rapresentation of each hex couple of this number. So 0xA3 is equivalent to 163 in decimal and 25 is equivalent to 37. So my list should be
l = [37, 163]

Comment: @MarkDickinson, it works, too! Thanks for your solution!

Comment: Almost duplicate of [Converting int to bytes in Python 3 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3) (converting bytes to list is trivial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic approach:

```
In [10]: def by_two_byte(number, mod=16*16):
    ...:     rest, rem = number // mod, number % mod
    ...:     if not rest:
    ...:         return [rem]
    ...:     else:
    ...:         return by_two_byte(rest, mod) + [rem]
    ...:
    ...:

In [11]: by_two_byte(300)
Out[11]: [1, 44]

In [12]: by_two_byte(9635)
Out[12]: [37, 163]
```

You could also do this iteratively, but likely it won't be necessary unless you are dealing with *very large integers*. Note, the above function takes `int` input, so pass it `int('300')` if you want to start with a string.

Note the way this generalizes:

```
In [13]: 0xaf23ff65
Out[13]: 2938371941

In [14]: by_two_byte(2938371941)
Out[14]: [175, 35, 255, 101]

In [15]: list(map(hex,by_two_byte(2938371941)))
Out[15]: ['0xaf', '0x23', '0xff', '0x65']

In [16]: 0x4f8ac # odd number of hexadecimal digits
Out[16]: 325804

In [17]: list(map(hex,by_two_byte(325804)))
Out[17]: ['0x4', '0xf8', '0xac']
```

Dispensing with the decimal literals, using hexadeciml literals:

```
In [18]: list(map(hex, by_two_byte(0xfffffffff)))
Out[18]: ['0xf', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff']

In [19]: list(map(hex, by_two_byte(0xfafbfcfd)))
Out[19]: ['0xfa', '0xfb', '0xfc', '0xfd']
```

Comment: You could replace rest, rem = number // mod, number % mod with rest,rem = divmod(number,mod)

Comment: @SamCraig I could, but I prefer using the operators to save on a function call. It's a silly micro-optimization, but it bothers me all the same, and I find the operator version just as readable...

Comment: Aren't operators really not just function calls as well? So you're trading one function call for two function calls.

Comment: @mkrieger1 they are, but they are optimized, since `divmod` could be *anything*, since you could easily do `def divmod(x,y): return 'foo'`. You can time it yourself, the operator version is faster. Essentially, when you sue the operator Python can go directly to the correct function, whereas if you use the function, it has to resolve the name first.

Comment: Also, can't you just use the hexadecimal literals in your examples `In [14]` and `In [17]`, and remove `In [13]` and `In [16]`? Or did I miss the point for explicitly showing inputs 13 and 16?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I *could* have used hexadecimal literals, probably that is more clear...

Comment: @mkrieger1 I guess I just want to be explicit that hexadecimal literals get interpreted as normal `int`s.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Very good! It is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think you accidentally used my function in the last few lines of your answer ;)

Comment: @yinnonsanders whoops!

Answer (score 2):

For an iterative approach:

```
def convertToByteList(num):
    byteList = []
    while num > 0:
        byteList.insert(0, num & 0xFF)
        num = num >> 8

    return byteList
```

Or in one line:

```
[num >> (8*i) & 0xFF for i in range((num.bit_length() - 1) // 8,-1,-1)]
```

This uses shifting and bit masking to extract each byte, and uses the length of the integer in bits to determine how long the list should be.

Comment: Bitewise operators for the win! I really, really like this solution.

Comment: @itsp You're welcome, also added a list comprehension version.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 3, then the [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) method does most of what you need:

```
>>> n = 300
>>> n.to_bytes(2, "big")
b'\x01,'
>>> list(n.to_bytes(2, "big"))
[1, 44]
```

That `2` is the number of bytes in the output; it's a required argument. You can compute how many bytes you need for a given `n` using the [`int.bit_length`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) method:

```
>>> n = 9635
>>> nbytes = -(-n.bit_length() // 8)  # divide by 8, round up
>>> list(n.to_bytes(nbytes, "big"))
[37, 163]
```

And a larger example:

```
>>> n = 2160376691
>>> list(n.to_bytes(-(-n.bit_length()//8), "big"))
[128, 196, 187, 115]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you're trying to convert you decimal integer to a hex digits pair. For small (16-bit decimal ints), you can do it like this:

```
>>> list(divmod(300,256))
[1, 44]

>>> list(divmod(9635,256))
[37, 163]
```

Comment: Yes, but this method doesn't work with number larger than 65536.

Comment: @itsp yeah, you need to strip off two hexadecimal places at a time, my solution basically recurses on the above...

Comment: @itsp, of course it doesn't. I've explicitly stated that it works only for 16-bit ints. **The solution for larger numbers in left as an exercise for the reader**.