# How to encode string to bytes in python?

Tags: string, python-3.x, character-encoding, int, hex

I want to take an integer, that will be between 0 and 255, convert that to a hex string eg. `'\xff'` and then cast that to bytes to end up with `b'\xff'`. I had assumed that the following would work.

```
data_num = 255
data = chr(data_num)
data_byte = data.encode()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: I found the answer to this here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider using the built-in `hex` function?

```
data = hex(255)
data = data.encode()
print(data, type(data))
```

Output:

```
b'0xff' <class 'bytes'>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that `b'0xff'` has a length of 4, for my purposes I need the output to be exactly `b'\xff'`