# How do I loop through every possible value of a byte in python?

Tags: python, cryptography

I am conducting a Padding Oracle Attack for my Information Security course. Without getting into the details of the attack, I need to have a for loop that loops through all possible 1 byte hex values.

Pseudo-code of what I need to do:

```
for x in range('\x00', '\xFF'):
    replace last byte of ciphertext with byte
    perform padding check
```

I cannot figure out how to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3) solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Bytes are really just integers in the range 0-255 (inclusive), or in hex, 0 through to FF. Generate the integer, then create the byte value from that. The `bytes()` type takes a list of integers, so create a list of length 1:

```
for i in range(0xff):
    b = bytes([i])
```

If you store the ciphertext in a [`bytearray()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray-objects), you could even trivially replace that last byte by using the integer directly:

```
ciphertext_mutable = bytearray(ciphertext)
for i in range(0xff):
    ciphertext_mutable[-1] = i  # replace last byte
```