# bytes().decode proviedes neither Error nor Output

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

```
print(bytes(97).decode('utf8'))
```

This line is part of my project and its giving me a headache for a while now, If I run this the Output is just an empty space, no Error or anything else. The 97 came from encoding the 'a' with utf8. I want do work with the encoded numbers so I changed them to Integers, but I cant get them to decode once I'm done working with them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting int to bytes in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you run `bytes(97)` the output is `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\...`
but if you run `bytes([97])` you get `b'a'` which I assume is what you expected.

**EDIT:**

I just found this question which explains the why:

[Converting int to bytes in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3)