# Convert a signed long to ASCII binarized hexidecimal format python

Tags: python, hex

Given a 8-bytes long signed value, like 3576757170468630901, I would like to convert it to ASCII binarized hexadecimal:

For example:

```
>> hex(3576757170468630901).encode('ascii')
b'0x31a331b2319d3175'
```

What I am looking for is the following format:

```
b'\x31\xa3\x31\xb2\x31\x9d\x31\x75'
```

I am not sure how can I generate it? Should I break each block and convert it myself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting int to bytes in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python 3 there is now `to_bytes()` which may help here:

```
v = 3576757170468630901
print(hex(v))
print(v.to_bytes(8, 'big'))
```

Output:

```
0x31a331b2319d3175
b'1\xa31\xb21\x9d1u'
```