# Python byte literal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I supect this a bit of a python newbie question, but how do you write a single byte (zero in this case) to a file?

I have this code:

```
f = open("data.dat", "wb")
f.write(0)
f.close()
```

But on the write line it is giving the error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'

I guess I need to replace 0 with a byte literal, but can't figure out the syntax. All my searches are telling me about converting strings to bytes. I tried `0B` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to write the integer `0`. That's a Python object.

I suppose you want to write the null byte. In that case, issue `f.write(b'\0')`.

`b'\0'` is short for `b'\x00'`.

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off converting int to byte this way:

```
b = bytes([0])
```

Alternatively, you may be better off using the struct library:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

You may gain looking at [Converting int to bytes in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Comment: Both Python 2 (`'\0'`) and Python 3 (`b'\0'`) have byte literals. (Python 2 *called* the type `str`, but fixing the string-vs-bytes dichotomy was one of the major goals of Python 3.)

Comment: @chepner I figured it out and fixed my answer.