# Pass raw bytes as a literal to hashlib.md5

Tags: python, ascii, encode

Looks like python3 treats regular strings as unicode...

```
import hashlib
h= hashlib.md5()
h.update ('abcd')
```

cause the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

forcing me to do encode it before:

```
import hashlib
h= hashlib.md5()
h.update ('abcd'.encode ('ascii', 'replace'))
```

which is tedious since the structure occurs several dozens of time in the program.

I was wondering if there is an alternative to not use encode everywhere in the program.

Comment: `h.update (b'abcd')`

Comment: Probably not the optimal solution. But you can use `b'abcd'` instead of the string directly.

Comment: Python (3.x) does not "treat" regular strings "as Unicode"; Unicode **is the standard** that explains **what strings are**. The first version of the Unicode standard came out **over thirty years ago**; expecting to work with text on a 1 character = 1 byte basis is inexcusable today. "I was wondering if there is an alternative to not use encode everywhere in the program." Write your own function to wrap up those steps together. Alternately, if it is a literal, then don't have a string in the first place; have a `bytes` object - since you apparently have specific bytes that you wish to hash.

Comment: Thankfully, it does. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit *" All text is Unicode; "*

Comment: thank you all to the help. Yes, I have to treat it as b'simple string' and not as unicode strings which is the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a byte literal using the `b` prefix. i.e.

```py
import hashlib

h = hashlib.md5()
h.update(b"abcd")
```

References

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes

Comment: **If** this answers the question (and it is not quite clear to me how OP expects things to work, or the *context* of where the data comes from), then I would argue that the question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61780683/python-byte-literal.

Comment: I could go either way with it. My thinking is that this is more specifically about how to prevent calling `<string>.encode("ascii")` on a unicode literal. The title should probably be updated to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, strings *are* unicode. From the data model in the documentation:

> A string is a sequence of values that represent Unicode code points.

Additionally, `hashlib` hashes expect bytes-like objects to be used for initialization and updates.

So next to `encode` you can use:

- Bytes literals `b"abcd"`.
- The built-in function `bytes`, e.g. `bytes("abcd", "ascii")` in case you can't use literals.