# Questions about rs232 serial communication using python in windows

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, serial-communication

I'm currently trying to do RS232 communication using python.

The communication manual is as shown in the picture below.

[Instruction Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9bFG.png)

[Stirrer control(rpm up to 1000)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP37B.png)

I followed it and created the communication code, but it's not working, so I'm contacting you guys.

The code below sends a signal to the OS20 pro model overhead stirrer to change the rpm value to 1000.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600, timeout=1)
def calculate_checksum(data): #calculate checksum
    checksum = sum(data[1:]) & 0xFF
    return bytes([checksum])

print("Start")
print(ser.name)

command = b'0xfe0xB10x030x00'
checksum = calculate_checksum(command)
command_with_checksum = command + checksum

ser.write(command_with_checksum)

print("Reading")
read = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
print("Reading: ", read)

ser.close()
```

Is there something wrong with the checksum side? Or is it because I made the command wrong and sent it?

Thank you for reading.

Sends a signal to the OS20 pro model overhead stirrer to change the rpm value to 1000.

Comment: Maybe `command = bytearray([0xfe, 0xB1, 0x03, 0x00])`

Comment: Or you can use `command = b'\xfe\xB1\x03\x00'`. [Python bytes literal has extra characters that aren't hex, but alter the value of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16862497/9014308), [Python byte literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61780683/9014308), [classmethod int.from_bytes(bytes, byteorder='big', *, signed=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sadly there is no response from the motor, it's really hard to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead. may work:)

```
command_with_checksum = command.decode("utf-8") + checksum.decode("utf-8")
ser.write(command_with_checksum.encode())
```