# Convert arbitrary int to bytes

Tags: python, arrays, struct

How can I use `struct` to convert an arbitrary `int` (unsigned, signed, long long,... just `int` in Python) to a byte sequence (`bytes`)?

If I read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) correctly, I would need to decide on a format string depending on the sign or length of the int, but in Python I don't really have this distinction. I'm trying to convert an arbitrary int to `bytes` and re-create the `int` again from the sequence of bytes (`bytes`).

Here are some attempts which failed:

```
# int is too big
>>> struct.unpack('>i', struct.pack('>i', -12343243543543534))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
>>> -12343243543543534
-12343243543543534
>>> struct.unpack('>q', struct.pack('>q', -12343243543543534))
(-12343243543543534,)

# again, integer value is too big, but can be represented as integer (below)
>>> struct.unpack('>q', struct.pack('>q', -1234324354354353432432424))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: int too large to convert
>>> -1234324354354353432432424
-1234324354354353432432424
```

Alternatively, I could also use the largest "container" to convert to `bytes` and "up cast" when turning the `bytes` back into an integer, but then I would know which format string is safe (=largest) to use.

#### `bytes` approach

[`bytes(int)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3) seems to have the same problem and requires to know about the sign:

```
>>> bytes(i)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: negative count
>>> i
-123432432432232
```

#### `int.to_bytes` / `int.from_bytes`

With a sufficiently large number of bytes, I can store "any" integer value, but it is still required to know about the sign.

```
>>> int(-1234324354354353432432424).to_bytes(64, 'little')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: can't convert negative int to unsigned
```

```
>>> int(-1234324354354353432432424).to_bytes(64, 'little', signed=True)
b'\xd9\xf0;\xd5l5\x86$\x9f\xfa\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

```
>>> int.from_bytes(int(-1234324354354353432432424).to_bytes(64, 'little', signed=True))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: from_bytes() missing required argument 'byteorder' (pos 2)
```

```
# no sign parameter
>>> int.from_bytes(int(-1234324354354353432432424 + 1).to_bytes(64, 'little', signed=True), 'little')
13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882810712245592079295573651673
```

```
# actual number
>>> int.from_bytes(int(-1234324354354353432432424 + 1).to_bytes(64, 'little', signed=True), 'little', signed=True)
-1234324354354353432432423
```

Comment: Just to be clear: You want to store an integer? Ideally in a binary format? A bytearray is something different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting int to bytes in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "list of byte" to be precise (I didn't mean `bytearray`)...

Comment: A list of byte is for example ``[b'\xff', b'\xd4', b'%', b'\xe2', b'\xa9', b'6', b'\x01', b'\x12']``, is that really what you want?

Comment: Either that or `b'\xff\xd4%\xe2\xa96\x01\x12'` (`<class 'bytes'>`). Either way is fine. I want to write it to a binary file and read it again.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: no the link doesn't answer the question. It's the same problem. You need to know the sign.

Comment: Did you try using [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30375198) to the linked question)?

Comment: Yes, same problem (you'd need to know the sign). Let me update my post...

Comment: What do you mean by "you need to know the sign"? What is the problem with that? You can specify whether the number is signed or unsigned in `to_bytes`.

Comment: Is the last example you have shown not exactly what you want?!

Comment: You can't just write this `int` into a file and read it from that file without also storing the sign (you need to specify a `signed` parameter in order to reassemble this integer correctly). I was hoping to "dump" the memory content of this integer into a file (as `bytes`) and read it again without worrying about size of sign.

Comment: You don't need to know *which* sign the number has. You need to know *that* it has a sign. There is no way around that.

Comment: Bummer... I was hoping to get around that. (+/- sign... which... or when you assume only - is a sign, then yes "that")

Comment: Take note that using ``int.to_bytes`` with ``signed=True`` is the closest you can get to dumping the memory content. Said memory content includes an explicit sign.

Comment: Noted @MisterMiyagi - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `bytes(int)` seems to have the same problem and requires to know about the sign

No; this is not for the kind of conversion you have in mind *at all*. Observe:

```
>>> bytes(3) # 3 is the *length* of the result
b'\x00\x00\x00'
```

> With a sufficiently large number of bytes, I can store "any" integer value, but it is still required to know about the sign.

This is not a limitation you could possibly avoid even in theory. The stored byte data is *just data*; whether it represents a signed or unsigned value is an *interpretation of* that data that must be imposed upon it. There is no way in principle that you could take in `b'\x80'` and just *know* whether it should represent 128 or -128, just by looking at it; and *it does not matter* whether that value came from using the `struct` module, `int.to_bytes` or anything else. No tool you use can make the decision for you, because you are *not giving it any information with which the decision could be made*.

(Note that your use of the `struct` module *does* encode assumptions about signedness. For example, `q` denotes a *signed* 64-bit type; for the corresponding unsigned type, you would use `Q`.)

In short, what you are asking for does not make sense.

You can, of course, work around the limitation by either a) adopting a convention (you know whether to interpret the value as signed or unsigned because of the *context* in which you are interpreting the bytes), or b) explicitly adding that information (storing a byte that encodes the signedness of the value - but this hardly ever is done in the real world). That is to say: you can give your decoding mechanism the information to make the decision, or you can make the decision yourself.

---

> You can't just write this `int` into a file and read it from that file without also storing the sign (you need to specify a `signed` parameter in order to reassemble this integer correctly). I was hoping to "dump" the memory content of this integer into a file (as `bytes`) and read it again without worrying about size of sign.

You are, presumably, storing multiple values in the same file. That means that the foregoing is *not a real limitation anyway* - because you *already* have to make decisions about the *size* of the values you read from the file; where one ends and the next begins. Which is to say, in your example:

```
int.from_bytes(int(-1234324354354353432432424 + 1).to_bytes(64, 'little', signed=True), 'little', signed=True)
```

you tell yourself that you don't need to know the size for the `.from_bytes` call, but in a real application you still would - because you would be taking a slice of the file data, not the whole thing, and you would need to know the bounds of the slice.

Comment: Thanks. "No tool you use can make the decision for you" - I was hoping that since the origin is the Python type `int` (which doesn't differentiate between unsigned, signed, size) that the conversion to `bytes` would contain the sign and perhaps a fixed size, but that doesn't seem to be the case (instead, the standard binary encoding is used).

Comment: I settled for `numpy.save(f, np.asarray([value]))` and `numpy.load(f)[0]`. I realise that `struct` is a bit too low level for my needs.

Comment: The converted value contains a sign, but it doesn't contain a *signedness* - rather: a positive integer can be represented fundamentally in two different ways. There is no fixed size because the integer type in Python is arbitrary precision. If you have a value of `255` then you will need two bytes to represent it as signed but only one to represent it as unsigned.

Comment: that’s all understood. I wasn’t so much after a basic binary encoding compliant bit export (which struct seems to be doing), but an efficient (no parsing, etc.) bit stream serialisation. I was wrongly assuming that `struct` was the way to go. Thanks for your explanation and the comments, I realise that it isn’t.

Comment: I mean, it is *if you can dictate the types* and go ahead and use them blindly when parsing. That's how real-world binary formats work, after all. The *documentation* tells you whether a value is signed or unsigned and how many bytes are used.