# int.to_bytes length calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Probably a stupid question but I stumbled across the int.to_bytes() function and I can't explain why I have to add "+7" if I calculate the bytes length and there is no hint in the documentation. I am sure I miss some bit/byte calculation magic but I need a little help from the community here.

Example what confused me: `x.to_bytes((x.bit_length() + 7) // 8, byteorder='little')` from https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are 8 bits in a byte.  The +7 is just a cheesy way of making sure that the `// 8` is rounded up to the nearest whole byte.

Comment: @Samwise - that makes sense. I ran `x=10; x.bit_length()` on the python shell on python.org and got `4`. Makes sense that you would need to round to the nearest whole byte.

Comment: Another way to do it might be `x.to_bytes(math.ceil((x+1)/256), 'little')`.  Feels a little more straightforward to me to just divide by the int value of a full byte and use `math.ceil` than to use `bit_length` and do shenanigans with the number of bits.

Comment: @Samwise Ok, now I get it. I didn't think about that `//` is not the "true" division but the floor division. Now it makes sense for me.

For everyone didn't know the difference between true and floor division: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.2.html#pep-238-changing-the-division-operator

Answer (score 2):

`bit_length` returns the number of **bits** necessary to represent an integer in binary, excluding the sign and leading zeros. So

```
(x.bit_length() + 7) // 8
```

will just give you the number of **bytes** necessary to represent that integer `x`. You could also write something like

```
from math import ceil
ceil(x.bit_length() / 8)
```

to get the same number.

The method `to_bytes()` requires this **byte** length as its first argument.

To account for `x == 0`, use the `max` function to ensure that the number of bytes is at least one:

```
x.to_bytes(length=(max(x.bit_length(), 1) + 7) // 8, byteorder='little')
```

Comment: @Simon Fromme Thanks for the explanation but the missing link for me was that the `//` cuts off everything behind the point.