# Deterministic method to hash np.array -> int

Tags: python, numpy, hash, pyarrow

I am creating a system that stores large numpy arrays in `pyarrow.plasma`.
I want to give each array a unique, deterministic  `plasma.ObjectID`, `np.array` is not hashable sadly
My current (broken) approach is:

```
import numpy as np
from pyarrow import plasma
def int_to_bytes(x: int) -> bytes:
    return x.to_bytes(
        (x.bit_length() + 7) // 8, "big"
    )  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3
def get_object_id(arr):
    arr_id = int(arr.sum() / (arr.shape[0]))
    oid: bytes = int_to_bytes(arr_id).zfill(20)  # fill from left with zeroes, must be of length 20
    return plasma.ObjectID(oid)
```

But this can easily fail, for example:

```
arr = np.arange(12)
a1 = arr.reshape(3, 4)
a2 = arr.reshape(3,2,2)
assert get_object_id(a1) != get_object_id(a2), 'Hash collision'
# another good test case
assert get_object_id(np.ones(12)) != get_object_id(np.ones(12).reshape(4,3))
assert get_object_id(np.ones(12)) != get_object_id(np.zeros(12))
```

It also involves summing the array, which could be very slow for large arrays.
Feel free to assume that the `dtype` of `arr` will be `np.uint` or `np.int`.

I know think that it's impossible to never have a hash collision (I only have 20 bytes of ID and there are more than 2^20) possible inputs, so I am just looking for something that is either
a) cheaper to compute
b) less likely to fail in practice

or, ideally, both!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hashlib module has some routines for computing hashes from byte strings (typically used for CRC).  You can convert an ndarray into a bytes string with `ndarray.tobytes` however your examples will still fail because those arrays have the same bytes but different shapes.  So you could just hash the shape as well.

```
def hasharr(arr):
  hash = hashlib.blake2b(arr.tobytes(), digest_size=20)
  for dim in arr.shape:
    hash.update(dim.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))
  return hash.digest()
```

Exmaple:

```
>>> hasharr(a1)
b'\x9f\xd7<\x16\xb6u\xfdM\x14\xc2\xe49.\xf0P\xaa[\xe9\x0bZ'
>>> hasharr(a2)
b"Z\x18+'`\x83\xd6\xc8\x04\xd4%\xdc\x16V)\xb3\x97\x95\xf7v"
```

I'm not an expert on blake2b so you'd have to do your own research to figure out how likely a collision would be.

I'm not sure why you tagged `pyarrow` but if you're wanting to do the same on pyarrow arrays without converting to numpy then you can get the buffers of an array with `arr.buffers()` and convert these buffers (there will be multiple and some may be `None`) to byte strings with `buf.to_pybytes()`.  Just hash all the buffers.  There will be no need to worry about the shape here because pyarrow arrays are always one dimensional.

Comment: This is really close to working! The only issue with it is that if a1.shape has an entry larger than 256, `bytes(a1.shape)` raises `ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated the alg.  It allocates 4 bytes per dimension which should be good for most cases I think.  You could always make it dynamic to use as few as neccesary as a bonus exercise.

Comment: Cool I ended up just hashing the shape of the array and `arr[0].to_bytes()` to make it faster to compute the hash, but this was massively helpful!