# How to cast bytes to an int and back to the same bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting, integer, byte

I have an arbitrary `byte` in Python that I want to cast into a 64 bit integer and back into the same byte.

I am currently, using this to turn the `bytes` into an `int`, where `x` is a byte I am given:

```
int.from_bytes(x, "little")
```

But I'm struggling on how to use `int.to_bytes()` to convert it back to the same bytes because I'm unsure what to put for length, nothing seems to create the equivalent byte?

Comment: Can you give an example for `x`?

Comment: maybe you can convert the byte to a string and use the lenght of the string as the lenght

Comment: the byte is represented by b'\x00' so you can make it def func(x): return (len(str(x)) -3)/4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3 Look this answer !

Comment: Visit [Converting int to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3) Here you will find what you need !

Comment: @Luiz why convert to a strings? `bytes` objects have a length...

Comment: @Luiz that is **totally incorrect**, `len(str(x))`

Comment: Why not just `len(x)` as the length?

Comment: @Thiago Salgado I saw that post but it won't work. The difference is I am given a byte. That post is int to byte to int but my use case is byte to int to byte.

Comment: The byte length of a byte converted to an integer is `1` of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not understand you question, but consider this:

```
x = b'deadbeef'
print(f'x -> {x}')    # x -> b'deadbeef'

i = int.from_bytes(x, 'little')
print(f'i -> {i:,}')  # i -> 7,378,415,037,781,730,660

y = i.to_bytes(len(x), 'little')
print(f'y -> {y}')    # y -> b'deadbeef'


# If you don't know the original variable, you can compute the byte length
# like this:

bit_length = i.bit_length() + 1  # Including sign bit.
byte_length = (bit_length + 7) // 8

z = i.to_bytes(byte_length, 'little')
print(f'z -> {z}')    # z -> b'deadbeef'
```