# Writing the user input to a binary file in hex format using Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and was trying to do a simple job but I am having a problem.
I am trying to take a large number as input from user say 500 and write it to a file in hex format.
For this I tried to take a small number as first step and write it, but I get the error as below

```
10 
0xa 
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "temp.py", line 7, in <module>
    fp.write(bytes(('num',))) TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The sample code used is as below.

```
intval = int(input())
num = hex(intval)
print(num)
with open('hexFile.iotabin', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(bytes(('num',)))
    fp.close()
```

Could you let me know

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. For large number say 500, I would like to split it to two bytes while writing. Will to_bytes() be able to help once the issue above is resolved or is there any other simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

[`hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) returns a string instead of a number. `bytes(('num',))` should be `bytes((intval,))`.

This works for `0` - `255`, i.e., `0x0` - `0xff`:

```py
intval = int(input())

with open("hexFile.iotabin", "wb") as fp:
    fp.write(bytes((intval,)))
```

And `fp.close()` is unnecessary since `with` will close the file.

**2.**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30375198/13805358), yes, [`to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) is helpful for numbers larger than 255.

```
def int_to_bytes(x: int) -> bytes:
    return x.to_bytes((x.bit_length() + 7) // 8, "big")


intval = int(input())

with open("hexFile.iotabin", "wb") as fp:
    fp.write(int_to_bytes(intval))
```